# Dynamic environment variables in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, environment

Is it possible in some way to have dynamic environment variables in Linux?

I have a webserver where sites follow this layout:

```
site/
    qa/
    production/
```

I would like to have an environment variable (e.g. APPLICATION_ENV) that is set to "qa" when I'm in the qa directory, and to "production" when I'm in the production directory. The reason for this is that various sites can use many different processes that all need to know if it's the QA or production environment. Some sites use PHP under Apache, some use Node.js, some sites come with commandline tools, cron jobs, etcetera. I would like to have one authorative source on whether it's a QA or a production environment.

Comment: Is this for a shell script? You could just use `$(basename $(pwd))`

Comment: Not just for shell scripts. It would be easy if it was just that :-) There are many sites, with many different processes, scripts, etcetera. That is why I want *one* authorative source of the application environment (and I'd prefer to stick in in an environment variable if possible, because all Linux processes understand environment variables)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [`rvm`](http://beginrescueend.com/)'s override:

```
cd () { 
    if builtin cd "$@"
    then
        if [[ "$PWD" =~ /(qa|production)(/|$) ]]
        then
            export APPLICATION_ENV="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        else
            unset APPLICATION_ENV
        fi
        return 0
    else
        return $?
    fi
}
```

Just put this function in `.bashrc` or some other sourced environment file, and try to `cd` into `qa`, `production`, or one of their subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an executable script in one of `/bin` or `/usr/bin` directories and execute it from the site scripts. I don't see why you need to hack `cd`.

/usr/bin/which-version:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$PWD" =~ /(qa|production)(/|$) ]]
then
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
  echo "unknown"
fi
```

web-site:

`$env = system("which-version")`