# Managing multiple AWS accounts on the same computer

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I have multiple AWS accounts, and depending on which project directory I'm in I want to use a different one when I type commands into the AWS CLI.

I'm aware that the AWS credentials can be passed in via environmental variables, so I was thinking that one solution would be to make it set `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` based on which directory it's in, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Using Mac OS X, The AWS version is `aws-cli/1.0.0 Python/2.7.1 Darwin/11.4.2`, and I'm doing this all for the purpose of utilize AWS in a Rails 4 app.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [different profiles in the configuration file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-multiple-profiles), and just specify the profile that you want with:

```
aws --profile <your-profile> <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
```

If you don't want to type the profile for each command, just run:

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=<your-profile>
```

before a group of commands.

If you want to somehow automate the process of setting that environment variable when you change to a directory in your terminal, see [Dynamic environment variables in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497275/dynamic-environment-variables-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create an alias to aws command, which will export the AWS_CONFIG_FILE variable depending on the directory you are in.  Something like following (bash) may work.

First create following shell script, lets call it match.sh and put it in /home/user/

```
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=`if [[ "$PWD" =~ "MATCH" ]]; then echo "ABC"; else echo "DEF"; fi`
aws "$@"
```

Now define alias in ~/.bashrc script

```
alias awsdirbased="/home/user/match.sh $@"
```

Now whenever you wanna run "aws" comand instead run "awsdirbased" and it should work